# $host_name variable in SSL certificate path in Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to set up a default server in nginx with SSL, path to SSL certificate should contain sitename, something like that

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate ssl/$host_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/$host_name/privkey.pem;
```

and it doesn't work - in error log

```
cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl//fullchain.pem"
```

If I print this variable in headers with `add_header XX "$http_host";`
it shows the proper sitename. Is there any way to use sitename in certificate path? There are a lot of sites on my server with typical config so it's better for me to have just one config. Nginx version 1.18 and if I manually define some variable and put it in `ssl_certificate` parameter everything is working fine

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [$ssl_server_name](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_server_name) instead of `$host_name` or `$host` - see [an example](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) in the docs. You see, the certificate is required *before* the client sends its HTTP request, so at that time `$host_name` and `$host` are not defined.

But as those docs say,

> Note that using variables implies that a certificate will be loaded for each SSL handshake, and this may have a negative impact on performance.

So it's probably better to generate config files with fixed server names (and fixed certificate paths) for all your servers (using some kind of template).

Comment: It's worth also including the note from documentation saying "Note that using variables implies that a certificate will be loaded for each SSL handshake, and this may have a negative impact on performance". Thus it's best to avoid variable use for these directives. There are numerous configuration tools available (e.g. Ansible) to have "hardcoding" domain names in configuration less of an actual issue.